# panel linear model (using plm package) returns "model frame and formula mismatch in model.matrix()"

Tags: r, panel, linear-regression, plm

I'm trying to compute a linear model from panel data I have.

It looks something like this:

```
model <- plm((log(GDP)-log(lag(GDP,5))) ~ log(lag(GDP,5)) + (lag(Gini,5)) 
+ GFCF + Schooling, data=data.01, index=c("Country", "Year"), model="within")
```

The panel looks like this

```
Country  Year   GDP     Gini   GFCF  Schooling
A        1970   21400   0.33   0.22   10.11
A        1971   21350   0.34   0.23   10.70
A        1972   21600   0.33   0.23   10.90
B        1970   18500   0.29   0.17    9.80
B        1971   19000   0.28   0.17    9.90
B        1972   20800   0.28   0.15   10.50
```

Any idea why R keeps returning this?

```
series Gini, X are NA and have been removed
Error in model.matrix.default(mt, data = data, ...) : 
  model frame and formula mismatch in model.matrix()
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you do not have enough data for `lag(GDP, 5)` and `lag(Gini, 5)` to be computed and thus, you get NA as returned values. It looks like you only have 3 years available but you request the 5th lag of those variables.

Try `lag(data.01$GDP, 5)` directly in the console and look at that output [if data.01 is a pdata.frame, if not, convert it to such].